# How to ref the counter in the command AlgHeader?

Tags: counters, algpseudocode

First, a counter `AlgCounter` is defined.

Second, a new command `\AlgNo` is defined and the counter `AlgCounter` is used in the definition of `\AlgNo`.

Third, in order to draw three lines of an algorithm, a new command `\AlgHeader` is defined and `\AlgNo` is used the definition of `\AlgHeader`.

The question is how to ref the counter in the command `\AlgHeader`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcounter{AlgCounter}
\newcommand{\AlgNo}{\refstepcounter{AlgCounter}\textbf{\theAlgCounter}}

\newcommand{\AlgHeader}[1]{ 
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.7pt}\\
\noindent\underline{
    \makebox[0.98\textwidth][l]{
        \textbf{ Algorithm \AlgNo}: #1}
    }   
}

\newcommand{\AlgFooter}{\noindent\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{0.7pt}}

\begin{document}

    \AlgHeader{name1}\label{alg:nl1}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello world! 
    \end{algorithmic}
    \AlgFooter

    Algorithm \ref{alg:nl1} is ...

    \AlgHeader{name1}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello Java!  
    \end{algorithmic}
    \AlgFooter

    Algorithm \ref{alg:nl1} is ...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `algorithm` environment instead; your small changes to the default appearance can be dealt with by defining a new float style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% define a new float style (based on the “ruled” style)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\floatc@dowtia[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1}: #2\par}
\newcommand\fs@dowtia{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}%
  \let\@fs@capt\floatc@dowtia
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.7pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule height 0.7pt\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{dowtia}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{name1}\label{alg:nl1}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello world! 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg:nl1} is ...

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{name2}\label{alg:nl2}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello Java!  
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg:nl2} is ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

For long algorithms, we can reproduce the working of the `algorithm` environment, so we'll have a uniform appearance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% define a new float style
\makeatletter
\newcommand\floatc@dowtia[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1}: #2\par}
\newcommand\fs@dowtia{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}%
  \let\@fs@capt\floatc@dowtia
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.7pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule height 0.7pt\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue
}
% define a longalgorithm environment
\newenvironment{longalgorithm}[1][]
 {% the optional argument is ignored
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \hrule height .7pt depth 0pt \kern2pt
  \def\@captype{algorithm}%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}%
  \def\@fs@capt##1##2{{\@fs@cfont ##1}: ##2\par}%
  \def\caption{\refstepcounter\@captype\@dblarg{\float@caption\@captype}}%
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\unvbox\@floatcapt}%
  \def\ALG@endalgorithmic{\par\nobreak\kern2pt\hrule height 0.7pt\kern 2pt}%
 }
 {\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{dowtia}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{name1}\label{alg:nl1}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello world! 
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg:nl1} is ...

\begin{longalgorithm}
\caption{name2}\label{alg:nl2}
    \begin{algorithmic} 
        \Require{some input}
        \Ensure{some output}
        \State Hello Java!  
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{longalgorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg:nl2} is ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could always use `longalgorithm`, but for short ones it's much better if they're floats.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I intended to avoid the float environment "algorithm" to make long algorithms look perfect. So, I wrote the code. But I don't know how to ref  the counter embedded in two commands.

Comment: @DOWTIA Added the requested `longalgorithm` environment.